# Facebook loading images from another sites with given link

Tags: php, python, facebook

I want to know how facebook can extract images from given link. If you could please help me. Here is screen of what I mean. [Facebook screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EWr5.png)

Comment: Facebook fetches the HTML. Parses it and choose images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read up on the Document Object Model:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model

This is an extremely general question, and there are many, many ways to do it. Jquery's [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) will do it, as an example, if you search for an img tag. Pretty much every language has a library for navigating the DOM. Looking at the tagged languages in your question, you've got [PHP's DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [python's xml.dom](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html). If you're super new to this stuff, you should look into graph theory and specifically [tree data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)), because that's the core idea of DOM.